# Composite control from LinearLayout get messed up when replaced with merge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I want to create a composite view from a bunch of controls, by extending a LinearLayout.
I'm using an XML file to specify the inner layout of my custom control. I'm inflating the custom control from the code via `LayoutInflater`.

### The Problem is:

If i replace the root `LinearLayout` element to a `merge` element in the XML, my whole layout fall apart. If I don't, then I only encapsulated a `LinearLayout` with my custom one.

### The question is:

What do i have to change in the merge layout, so my view looks like how a linear layout should?

## How it looks like:

With `LinearLayout` (this is how i want it to look like):
http://oi45.tinypic.com/2pqwby1.jpg

With `merge` (this is the tag i want to use):
http://i45.tinypic.com/155j4o0.png

## The code:

### TowerLayout.java (no problems here, just in case):

```
public class TowerLayout extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {

    public TowerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tower_layout, this, true); //this is what i want to use.
        //((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root)).setOnClickListener(this); //this is the current ugly workaround.
        this.setClickable(true);
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Foo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

### What i have in Tower_Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:duplicateParentState="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TowerA"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Basic information"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:text="16m"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="100sp" />
```

### What i want in Tower_Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:duplicateParentState="true">

    ...

</LinearLayout>

...

</merge>
```

### One more thing:

I know, the screenshots are from the eclipse designer, but believe me: they look like this on android phone as well.

Comment: Are you sure `TowerLayout` extends `LinearLayout`? From the images it seems to extend a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Where are you setting the `android:orientation` for your `LinearLayout`s? Both the parent `TowerLayout`, and the child inside the `merge` tag. It shouldn't matter much, but I've seen some strange layouts when it wasn't set.

Comment: @Luksprog Yes, I'm 100% sure it extends from the LinearLayout. The code/xml are 100% Copy + Paste

Comment: @Geobits From now on, you are my personal hero. That was the problem. I was searching for hours now. :) After i set the orientation explicitly magic just happened :) Thank you very much.

Comment: No prob, I'm glad it helped. I added it as an answer so you can close out the question and possibly help future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly set the `android:orientation` tag for your layouts(and any `LinearLayout`, ever). Android supposedly uses `horizontal` by default, but in my experience it just messes it up if it's not set, and leads to some very strange-looking layouts.